# Gradble sync failed with Jitpack git repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jitpack

I created my first android library and published it to GitHub.

Now a want to make other able to use it.

So a visited gitpack.io and followed the steps there.

The thing is, that my Gradle sync failed in the Project I want to use my lib, and the JitPack log says about a warning with missing maven plugin but build is successful.

Here my jitpack log
https://jitpack.io/com/github/ludev-studio/colorpicker-android/v1.0.0/build.log

and my libs build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28



defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

          testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-      core:3.0.2'
 }
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Check this guide - https://medium.com/@ome450901/publish-an-android-library-by-jitpack-a0342684cbd0

Comment: Thank you for your link but it ddidn't solved my problem.